# Simultaneously access environment from two R sessions

Tags: r, shiny, r6

Is it technically possible in R?

I would like to run a shiny instance with prepared R6 object (environment class), use its methods - mostly read only.
While at the same time as shiny app running I would like to call other methods of my R6 - read/write.
Shiny R session could be a host for my R6 object while the second session would be called from scheduled R script / interactively from R console.
Currently what I think I can do is to source R script directly from shiny under a button, but this limits interactivity.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly, but iI think you might be describing parallelization?

Comment: @Roland 2 parallel connections to R6 class doing totally different things. One connection could be also interactive R console.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you could save the environment to the server every so often, or on event/observation.

In your other session, you could load that saved object.

Comment: You cannot do this — [process isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_isolation) takes care of that. It sounds like what you’re after is [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). However, at its most basic, maybe think about simply persisting your changes to a file or a database.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The whole use case is about [high performance, in-memory, highly normalized data warehouse implementation in R](https://github.com/jangorecki/anchormodeling). I will use database only on start/shutdown instance but I would like to be able to load new data while instance in running.

Comment: No dice. You can look at other modes of IPC, of course: sockets or named pipes *may* be faster than writing to a file. Memory-mapped files are also faster than raw files because the serialisation overhead is omitted.

Comment: Probably not general enough for what you want, but two different sessions connected to the same application on the same server share global data. Using `<<-` on globally defined objects will dangerously propagate changes into (all) other sessions.

Comment: @StuartR.Jefferys AFAIK *same application on same server* will produce separate sessions and won't share any global data. If `<<-` would work then I should be able to `assign` to arbitrary environment object making it cross session storage. If works then it would be a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

This article describes the [scoping rules for Shiny apps](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html) and how to define global data with variously packaged code. Below is my example of a global variable holding data accessible to multiple sessions.

Run this app, then open a second tab/window in your browser and point it at the same connection. You can click the +1 button in one session to increment the shared max and local count. In the other session, you will not see any change until something triggers shiny to re-check the shared data, but clicking the +1 button there will update the local count, but also trigger update of the shared max data value. You can click the +1 button there several times until you have a new max, then go back to the first window and you can see the max is visible there too, once you click the +1 button to trigger an update. This works for multiple windows.

You have to do *something* to make a session check the data again to update. I didn't work too hard to make this happen without side effects. There should be some way to do a "refresh" based on whatever trigger you want. You can even use a timed poll to keep data in sync, like [this example](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/reactive-poll-and-file-reader.html) does with files.

The one caveat to this example is I have only tried with a local RStudio shiny server implementation. I don't know that it works this way on a real server. If it does not, please comment to that effect! It will probably not work this way on shinyapps.io or with any kind of cloud/load-balancing in general as you can't guarantee that two sessions share an app instance on one machine.

```
library(shiny)

globalMax <- 0

app <- shinyApp(
   ui= pageWithSidebar(
      headerPanel("Shared data demo"),
      sidebarPanel(
         actionButton("plusButton", "+1")
      ),
      mainPanel(
         verbatimTextOutput("sharedMax")
      )
   ),
   server= function(input,output){
      observe({
         if (input$plusButton > globalMax) {
            globalMax <<- input$plusButton
         }
      })
      output$sharedMax <- renderText({
         paste0( "Shared max value: ",  globalMax, "\n",
                 "Local value: ",  input$plusButton)
      })
   }
)

runApp(app)
```

Comment: how should I connect to it from separate R console when it is already running?

Comment: All code sharing data must be in the same app. Web browser sessions only share internal data because they are connected to the same app (the same url). You could connect from a console if you made it act like a browser/web-scraping tool, via a url connection, but data would be streamed across the net connection if you want it "out" of the app and into something else.

Comment: To accept it as an answer I would expect it to cover *You could connect from a console if you made it act like a browser/web-scraping tool*. This is in fact the whole point - how to connect to running app and alter data it uses without reloading from db. PS. I have 1 web browser session and 1 R console session, so not really interested into data shared between multiple web sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have done what you want accidentally - essentially 2 RStudio sessions running in parallel? On my Mac I just right-click RStudio and select New RStudio Window. I have done it on Windows as well but don't have access to one atm - should be similar. 
Running 2 sessions allows you to preserve and refer back to the original while you tweak the 2nd instance. With 2 monitors, this can be very handy for speeding up dev time on finicky details ;)

Comment: I'd say this is not what the OP wanted to know, he asked for sharing data between two R sessions in a shiny server (not starting two instances of RStudio)